# re.findall outputs blanks along with correct

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to get the list output to not have subgroups or empty spaces. *I'm trying to stick with a RegEx only solution* due to my re.split and array manipulation method is really janky and sort of slow.

**HTML file:** *(Notice that thing 3 & 4 have `/b/` before instead of `/a/`.)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>   
    <body></body>
        <a href="example.com/a/thing1"></a>
        <a href="example.com/a/thing2"></a>
        <a href="example.com/b/thing3"></a>
        <a href="example.com/b/thing4" ><img src="/thing4.png"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Python file:**

```
import re

html = open("help.html", "r").read()
links = re.findall('((?<=\.com\/a\/).*(?="))|((?<=\.com\/b\/).*(?=" ><))|((?<=\.com\/b\/).*(?="><\/a))',html)

print(links)
```

What will output when I run the above py file:

```
[('thing1', '', ''), ('thing2', '', ''), ('', '', 'thing3'), ('', 'thing4', '')]
```

What I want it to output:

```
[thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4]
```

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/RPGmxG/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the *capturing groups*. As stated in [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Empty matches are included in the result.
>
> The result depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern. If there are no groups, return a list of strings matching the whole pattern. If there is exactly one group, return a list of strings matching that group. If multiple groups are present, return a list of tuples of strings matching the groups. Non-capturing groups do not affect the form of the result.

An example of *capturing group* is `((?<=\.com\/a\/).*(?="))`, so the most external brackets shall be removed, same for the other 2 groups:

```
links = re.findall('(?<=\.com\/a\/).*(?=")|(?<=\.com\/b\/).*(?=" ><)|(?<=\.com\/b\/).*(?="><\/a)',HTML)
```

Output:

```
['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4']
```